# What was the involvement of the upper social classes of Russia in Kizhi?

Tags: russia, religion, architecture, social-class

[Kizhi Pogost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kizhi_Pogost), a [UNESCO World Heritage site](https://whc.unesco.org/en/list/544/), was built in the 17th - early 18th century in Karelia (north-west Russia). Its architecture is remarkable, and it's quite big. The only personality mentioned along with its construction is the builder *Master Nestor* (the name suggests a low social status).

I wonder what was the involvement of the upper social classes of Russia in this site? Did they give any money to fund the building? Were they making a pilgrimage to Kizhi? Or was it is built and frequented by the local peasants only?

[image]

Comment: How will you determine the quality of an answer? This post seems, to me, intended to initiate a discussion rather than answer a specific question.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I could find no information whatsoever, so this post was intended to find some :)

Comment: How a big public project was funded seems a legit (and even shrewd) question to me. I know for some local projects here in Tulsa, knowing that is really knowing the whole story of the project.

Comment: Russian internet is also silent on the matter. They only mention that the church was built in 1714,  as fire destroyed previous one. They also mention master Nestor, and in some cases Peter the Great, but I doubt this second version because there are no historical records. Likely funding came from local rich merchants, rather then nobility.